# More Iterations Of Gauss-Seidel With Scipy Infinite Norm

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a python code to solve linear systems with Gauss-Seidel Method, using Numpy and Scipy. I'm implementing the code and an example from the book: **'Numerical Analysis: Burden and Faires'**.
***The problem is I obtain the exact solution but with more iterations: 10 iterations with 0.0000001 tolerance but the book obtains the solution with only 6 iterations and 0.001 tolerance.***
I think the problem is because of infinity norm using scipy to calculate the error. When I don't use the error in the code (only iterations) I obtain the same result as the book. Here's my python code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as scp


def gauss_seidel(A, b, x_0, max_iterations=15, tolerance=0.0000001):
    L = -np.tril(A, -1)
    U = -np.triu(A, 1)
    v = np.diagonal(A)
    D = np.diag(v)
    DL = D - L
    Hg = np.linalg.inv(DL)
    Tg = Hg @ U
    Cg = Hg @ b

    n = A.shape[0]
    x = np.zeros(n)
    diff = np.zeros(n)
    error = 0.0
    k = 1

    while k <= max_iterations:
        x = Tg @ x_0 + Cg
        diff = x - x_0
        error = scp.linalg.norm(diff, ord=np.inf, axis=None) / \
            scp.linalg.norm(x, ord=np.inf)
        x_0 = x
        k += 1
        if(error < tolerance):
            break
    return x, k


A = np.matrix([
    [10, -1, 2, 0],
    [-1, 11, -1, 3],
    [2, -1, 10, -1],
    [0, 3, -1, 8]
])

b = np.array([6, 25, -11, 15])
x_0 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
solution = gauss_seidel(A, b, x_0, tolerance=0.001)
print('WITH TOLERANCE = 0.001')
print(
    f'Solution = {solution[0]} with {solution[1]} iterations')
solution = gauss_seidel(A, b, x_0)
print('WITH TOLERANCE = 0.0000001')
print(
    f'Solution = {solution[0]} with {solution[1]} iterations')
```

And this is my terminal output:

> WITH TOLERANCE = 0.001
> Solution = [ 1.00009128  2.00002134 -1.00003115 0.9999881 ] with 6 iterations
> WITH TOLERANCE = 0.0000001 Solution = [ 1.  2. -1.  1.] with 10 iterations

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your GS solver is nicely implemented! BUT: Is it important, that you run your own GS sover? If not, then the different scipy solvers are usually much faster than GS, even with stricter convergence criterias.

For this small equation system here, the direct solvers `np.linalg.solve()` and `scp.linalg.solve()` are up to 10 to 20 times faster than GS. For larger systems `[25,25]` and more, the iterative solvers are more suitable. `bicgstab` will be much faster than GS with increasing size. (but this example is too small to be effective).

```
%%timeit
solution = gauss_seidel(A, b, x_0, tolerance=0.001)
188 µs ± 7.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)


%%timeit
np.linalg.solve(A,b)
8.34 µs ± 937 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)


%%timeit
scp.linalg.solve(A,b)
19.4 µs ± 3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)


from scipy.sparse.linalg import bicgstab
%%timeit
X = bicgstab(A, b, x0=x_0, tol=1e-06, maxiter=None)
194 µs ± 15.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks. I know there's scipy solver. But this is not useful for me, i want to learn to implement GS for myself.